# Visual Studio for Mac Preview and SQL Server and Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio for Mac Preview on Mac and I wanted to see my options for using any persistent storage (preferably SQL SERVER). Is it possible to use Entity Framework using Visual Studio for Mac Preview.